# Unable to Retain the Result of a Word Game

Tags: python, persistence

I have created a very simple word game. You go through a word list one word at a time and if you know the word you can continue with the next word or if you do not know the word, you can save it to your list of new words. 
The script works fine as long as it is running, but once I quit the game, I lose all the saved words and the list of new words becomes empty.
I tried to use pickle, but it didn't work out. Here is my code:

```
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'tiger', 'puppy']
new_word = []

def get_item(a_list):
    ind = 0
    while ind < len(my_list):
        confirm_list = ['y', 'Y']
        confirm_list2 = ['n', 'N']
        confirm_list3 = ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']
        confirm = input('Type Y to continue or N to quit: ')
        if confirm in confirm_list:
            print(my_list[ind])
            ind += 1
            confirm_add = input('Type Y to add this word to New_Word list: ')
            if confirm_add in confirm_list:
                new_word.append(my_list[ind - 1])
                for item in new_word:
                    print(item)
            if ind == len(my_list):
                print('This is the last item.')
        if confirm in confirm_list2:
            print('Thanks for playing. See you again.')
            break
        if confirm not in confirm_list3:
            print('Please type Y or N in small or capital letters.')

get_item(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects in python (your list for example) are all temporary, they live in memory and they go away as soon as you exit Python or the Python program that created them.

So use **Pickle** instead!

```
>>> your_list = ["cat","dog"]
>>>
>>> import pickle
>>> 
>>> with open('your_list.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...   pickle.dump(your_list, f)
...
```

Then quit the program and open it again. Now type in

```
>>>import pickle
>>>with open('your_list.pkl','rb') as f:
...    your_newlist = pickle.load(f)
...
>>>your_newlist
["cat","dog"]
```

To make things more clear for you

You have a function `def get_item(a_list):`
in the end of the function use

`return list_you_need_to_store`

Then follow what I have given as code example using this returned *list*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your items to disk and reload it when you open the program again.

[Try a tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Comment: Could you please tell me the same thing in Python instead of English?

Comment: Also change your question to _Storing objects in memory after python exits_ to get any different answers / solutions.